# How to make a loading screen progress showing in percentage without using a different activity?

Tags: android, loading

I want to create a loading screen that could show the percentage (how much It has loaded). Is there a possible way to do that without using a different activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example show how to show percentage according to change on `SeekBar`. You can Apply this your situation.

[Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-czLT2Sppw)

Answer (score 0):

U can update TextView then setVisibility to GONE or use ProgressDialog.